# Disable recommendation bar on YouTube

Tags: chrome, youtube

I need an extension or a script for Google Chrome that can help me disable or completely hide YouTube’s right sidebar with all the other videos links (Recommendation Bar).

I get distracted a lot by those while doing work.

Comment: If you use "Theater Mode" on a video and zoom in a little bit, the recommendation bar will be moved outside the screen border. Alternatively, you could resize your browser window to only fit the player dimensions

Comment: @Timmy that's not exactly what i mean mate i need something that can disable them all together even if i m playing in a normal size i would not show any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Stylish

An extension for Google [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/stylish/), and [Safari](https://extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.sobolev.stylish-5555L95H45). With Stylish you can name and save CSS rules as "userstyles" with URL scopes using [these rules](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites). Stylish will apply them when relevant pages are visited. **Stylish can be used to hide page elements.**

#### Relevant Userstyle

To remove the sidebar from youtube.com:

- For Chrome, you must use the user interface on the `Add Style` page:

  - Enter `#watch7-sidebar-contents{display:none}` in the `code` section
  - Set `Applies to` = `URLs on the domain`
  - Enter `youtube.com` in the adjacent textbox
  - Press `add`
  - Press `save` in the top left
- For Firefox, you can create this style:

  ```
  @-moz-document domain("youtube.com") {#watch7-sidebar-contents{display:none}}
  ```

Comment: I used to use Stylish to hide the comment section on youtube.com. You can do that with `#watch-discussion{display:none}`